# Read from txt file - Save when a line-break occurs

Tags: java, string, line

I want to read from .txt file, but I want to save each string when an empty line occurs, for instance:

```
All
Of
This
Is
One
String

But
Here
Is A
Second One
```

Every word from `All` to `String` will be saved as one String, while every word from `But` and forward will be saved as another. This is my current code:

```
public static String getFile(String namn) {
    String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String filnamn = userHomeFolder + "/Desktop/" + namn + ".txt";
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner inFil = new Scanner(new File(filnamn));
    while (inFil.hasNext()) {
        String fråga = inFil.next();
        question.add(fråga);
    }
    inFil.close();

}
```

What and how should I adjust it? Currently, it saves each line as a single String. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a good question and it will get more views if you add a tag for the language your using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question is regarding java.
As you can see I changed return type of your method to List because returning single String doesn't make sense when splitting full text into multiple Strings.
I also don't know what `question` variable so I switched it with `allParts` being list of sentences separated by empty line(variable `part`).

```
public static List<String> getFile(String namn) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String filnamn = userHomeFolder + "/Desktop/" + namn + ".txt";
    int counter = 0;

    // this list will keep all sentence
    List<String> allParts = new ArrayList<String>(); s

    Scanner inFil = new Scanner(new File(filnamn));

    // part keeps single sentence temporarily
    String part = "";
    while (inFil.hasNextLine()) { 
        String fråga = inFil.nextLine(); //reads next line
        if(!fråga.equals("")) {       // if line is not empty then
                part += " " + fråga;      // add it to current sentence
            } else {                  // else     
                allParts.add(part);       // save current sentence
                part = "";                // clear temporary sentence
            }

        }
        inFil.close();
        return allParts;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!